# Security groups in slate

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate, foundry-phonograph

I have a dataset with writeback synced to phonograph. The table contains data by countries. Users should be able to access and edit their country data. How do I restrict user's viewer and editor access in slate?

I have created security groups by country. Should I use restricted views to control access or is there another way to do it in slate?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Restricted Views](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/security/restricted-views/index.html#restricted-views) will let you limit view & edit access on a per-user/per-country level, assuming you have a country attribute on the users and a corresponding field in your dataset.

FWIW I would suggest an [object type backed by a restricted view](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-permissioning/configuring-rv-access-controls/index.html#configure-restricted-view-backed-object-types) instead of writing directly to phonograph, if that's what you're currently doing. Note the warning on [this page in the docs about writing to Phonograph from Slate](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/references-writeback/index.html#write-back-data-to-phonograph).